# Drive is missing from My Computer but is visible in Disk Management, how do I get it to show up?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I bought a new PC case and installed my hardware in it. I have 2 HDDs but I can't access one of them (320GB). How can I fix this?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drive is partitioned and formatted, but you haven't assigned a drive letter to the volume.

In Disk Management, right-click on the volume (in your case, the one on Disk 0), select **Change Drive Letter and Paths...**, click on the **Add** button, and assign a drive letter to the volume.